# Click function, inside .off removed handler, want it back

Tags: jquery, click, handler

Need Your help.

I want to:

1. Click on DIV makes it .active
2. Click on SPAN inside DIV removes the .active from THIS DIV

There's DEMO of the way i tried to do this:

**http://jsfiddle.net/2RwJJ/**

```
$('div').on( 'click', function() {

  if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) 
    $(this).addClass('active');

  // SPAN pressed
  $('div.active span').click( function() {
    $('div.active').off();                         // removing DIV handler
    $('div.active').removeClass('active');
 });
});
```

**Problem:** once i've clicked DIV and then SPAN in it, **i cannot click it with the jquery action further times, only once in the element**

Am I doing something wrong with handlers? Please tell me how to do this.

Comment: Why are you bind event in event handler? Do you want [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jwG43/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
$( function() {

  $('div').click(function() {

    if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) 
      $(this).addClass('active');
  });
     // x pressed
 $('body').on('click','div.active span', function() {     
     $(this).parent().removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/9Rxe5/)**

Answer (score 1):

Since the active class is creating dynamically, you need to use delegate for binding click event

```
$('document').ready(function () {

    $('div').on('click', function () {

        if (!$(this).hasClass('active'))
            $(this).addClass('active');

    });
    $(document).on("click", "div.active span", function () {

        $(this).parent().removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2RwJJ/1/)